# Dynamically construct RESTful route using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to write a helper method that accepts the name of a plural resource and returns a corresponding link. The essence of the method is:

```
def get_link(resource)
  link_to "#{resource.capitalize}", resource_path
end
```

—Clearly the `resource_path` part above doesn't work. What I'd like is to be able to pass `foos` to get `foos_path` and `bars` to get `bars_path` etc. How can I do that? I can't quite work out the syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def get_link(resource)
  link_to "#{resource.capitalize}", send("#{resource}_path")
end
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. Out of interest, what is the receiver of the send message at this point?

Comment: To answer my own question - when no receiver is specified then it's self, which in this case is ActionView::Base because it's in a helper method.

Answer (score 2):

```
def get_link(resource)
  link_to(resource.to_s.titleize, send("#{resource}_path"))
end
```

The to_s call on resource is to support passing symbols as resource.
So

```
get_link("foos")
```

will work and also

```
get_link(:foos)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to construct a RESTful route with a member:

```
send("edit_#{resource}_path".to_sym, @resource)
```