# No route matches controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, send

In my rails 3 app, I have a route which shows up as follows while calling rake routes:

```
topic_snippets GET /topics/:topic_id/snippets(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"snippets"}
```

In routes.rb

```
resources :topics do
 member do
  get 'get_topics'
 end
 resources :snippets, :only => [:index]
end
```

In my view, I am referencing this route as follows (where @name = "snippets"):

```
<%= send("topic_#{@name}_path")%>
```

When executing the previous line, I get the following routing error, not sure why:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"snippets"}
```

Update: I found another question whose responses seem to imply that the above should work: [Dynamically construct RESTful route using Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744592/dynamically-construct-restful-route-using-rails)

Thanks
Anand

Comment: But what is `@topic` and perhaps more importantly, what is that object's `id`?

Comment: The @topic parameter seems irrelevant - even if I remove it, I get the same error.

Comment: I just removed the @topic parameter from the question

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of your routes.rb file?

Comment: I have added the routes.rb file portion above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found it - Ryan's comment provided the clue.

I wasnt passing in @topic, which is required. If I remove @topic, it tries to just get at /snippets/ which doesn't have a route. I set @topic to a valid topic before calling this line and it works. Thanks, Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<%= send(eval("topic_#{@name}_path"), @topic)%>
```

Comment: I tried using eval - it gives me the same error, except this time it shows me the location in rails code where the routing error was raised.